# Why tableview's delegate method heightForRowAtIndexPath: executes one more time?

Tags: ios, uitableview, ios8

my platform is ios8 and xcode 6.3.1
tableview's delegate like this:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
          return 3;
}



- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
           return 1;
}
```

so, the delegate of heightForRowAtIndexPath:  should be execute three times , but my code execute four, why ?

My code :

init tableView

```
- (void)setupTableView {
    _selectTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    _selectTableView.delegate = self;
    _selectTableView.dataSource = self;
    _selectTableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;

    [self.view addSubview:_selectTableView];
}
```

other delegate method:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSInteger section = indexPath.section;
  static NSString *identified = @"selectCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identified];

  if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identified];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
  }

  return [self cellWith:cell andSection:section];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)cellWith:(UITableViewCell *)cell andSection:(NSInteger)section {
  ....
  return cell;

}


- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  CGFloat height = 0;
  if (section != SVCellTypeHot) {
    height = 5;
  }
  return height;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, kScreenSize.width, 5)];
  [footerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

  return footerView;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  CGFloat height = 0;

  switch (indexPath.section) {
    case SVCellTypeBanner:
    {
      height = kHeaderViewHeigth;
    }
      break;
    case SVCellTypeRecommand:
    {
      height = kRecommandViewHeight;
    }
      break;
    case SVCellTypeHot:
    {
       height = kHotViewHeight;
    }
      break;

    default:
      break;
  }

   return height;
}
```

Comment: Log the index path and see what rows it's being called for. Also, set a break point to see what is calling it.

Comment: the log output like this: NSLog(@"%ld, %ld", indexPath.section, indexPath.row);  the result :  1 0, 0 0, 1 0,  2 0

Comment: but the delegate cellForRowAtIndexPath:  just execute 3 times

Comment: Do you have other code that may change the height of indexPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath` allows the delegate to specify rows with varying heights. If this method is implemented, the value it returns overrides the value specified for the rowHeight property of UITableView for the given row. There is no guarentee that this method can only be called 'section count * item count' times in the UITableView. As you can tell from its name, it will calculate the height for the cells at `IndexPath`, so combining the `re-using` technique, this method will be called many times, as long as it needs to calculate the height for cell at `IndexPath`

So actually, it is a system behaviour to decide how many times it should be called and when. In your comment, it seems like something changed in indexPath {1-0} so `heightForRowAtIndexPath` is called twice for {1-0}. You might need to check have you changed any content that cause iOS to re-calculate the cell's height.

Without knowing more details, this is the best we can do to provide you some clues to debug. However, you should not rely on how many times it calls `heightForRowAtIndexPath`, again, this can be called at any time, as long as you scroll or change any frame inside that cell

Comment: i do not scroll it , i refresh my question , please see again

Comment: what is the implementation of `(UITableViewCell *)cellWith:(UITableViewCell *)cell andSection:(NSInteger)section`? I don't see the details, but only a `return cell`. Have you changed anything inside `cellWith`?

Comment: BTW, I don't see why you need to dig into this issue? Just for knowledge or curious? If this is the case, try use LLDB and print out the stack trace in the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` you think is redundant, and maybe you could see some clues why it is called one more time from the stack trace.

Comment: this question in my project , when calculate cell's height is not correct , e   i just know how to use 'po ' with LLDB  ,  thank you , i'll check it again

Comment: use 'bt' so it can print stack trace. We need to know `cellWith` details, or you should check do you changed any frame in `cellWith`? Other code seems fine. BTW, if you think your problem is solved, you should accept one answer or up vote, or update your question with more details

Comment: i found  a strange question : init a tableView , the dataSource method : section and row just return 1 , but heightForRowAtIndexPath: execute four times !!!  i don't do anything .

Comment: as I said, this is a system behavior and you have no control of it, and you should only care about feeding the right value

Answer (score 0):

`heightForRowAtIndexPath:` will execute as many times as it needs to. If you are scrolling, for example, it will execute as offscreen cells are about to come onscreen. That method should always be able to provide the correct height and you normally shouldn't be concerned with how often it's called. `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` executes 3 times as it should.

Comment: i know the re-use ,but i do not scroll it

Comment: I don't see why anyone would ever be concerned with how often heightforrow is getting called unless it's getting called so often (100000+) times per ms that it affects performance. As far as I know, the code that determines when to call this method is Apples private code. You can't control what it does. The delegate is simply supposed to return the height when the function is called. Basically I think it's probably a minor apple bug or something out of your control. Just out of curiosity, why are concerned that the method is getting called four times instead of three?

Comment: thank you , i'll check it again , maybe something out of my controll